# Using Iframe for cross domain login token

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm developing a website and there's a feature where a user does not have to login anymore if he/she has already logged in (in the same browser). I use token which is saved on the localstorage to achieve that. But, the client wants to use different domain for the main website and the login portal. I found a solution which uses Iframes to achieve a somewhat localstorage sharing system.

So the question is:
Is it considered a bad practice to use Iframes for authenticating token? Specifically for cross domain logins.

If so, do you have any better alternatives for a cross domain login system which uses a token like my case above?

Thank you!

---

**EDIT:**`Here's the whole process

1. The user login from login.com
2. The server authenticate the login and gives a token to login.com
3. A script in login.com saves the token (currently in localstorage)
4. When the user open website.com, I want to retrieve the token from login.com and authenticate it to the server (this is where I use Iframes)

Comment: Alternative would be use server to make request to other domain or even a new window but if it is working with iframe it should be fine

Comment: hi! @charlietfl do you have any reference that I can read? Thanks!

Comment: No, not really. Just experience and knowing there are often numerous ways to solve a specific issue

Comment: @charlietfl ah yes I agree with you! That's why I'm asking this because there could be better solutions for this situation :) Thanks!

Comment: Can't really be answered with a "better" solution without knowing a lot more about the whole process

Comment: @charlietfl Ah I added the process of my login system. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: Learn how OAuth works

Comment: Hi @epascarello I did learn about OAuth but I have a limited knowledge about it. The problem is about getting the token that does not exist at all from the website as the token only saved on the login site. But I'll dig OAuth again in case I missed something. Thanks :)